# Secret Message Puzzle

Tags: cipher

Mr. Lavesh is on a secret mission and it's 5 January so he wants to send a message to her daughter Arshika.

Mr. Lavesh got a secret device by which he can only use below words for sending the message.

> Piano, Numb, Company, Racial, Mozetta, Dining, Traitor, Meou, Quintana, legacy, Saphire, Trick, Orange, Frozen, Missi.

Mr. Lavesh sends the following message to his daughter:

> Company Piano Numb Dining Racial Mozetta Traitor Meou Legacy Quintana Trick Missi Orange Frozen Sapphire

What does Mr. Lavesh's Message?

Comment: Does his daughter know which that those are the only words he can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message says

> CONGRATULATIONS

You get it by

> Taking individual letters from each word, alternating between the first letter and last letter.